# Change transition from linear to decelerate in EDC script

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

In EDC, I can use `script`s in `collections/group` to make animation:

```
group { "my_group";
  script {
     public my_anim(val, Float:pos) {
        set_tween_state(PART:"elm.text", pos, "state_begin", 0.0, "state_end", 0.0);
     }
     public start_my_anim() {
        anim(1 /*duration in seconds*/, "my_anim", 1 /*I have no idea about this param*/);
     }
  }

  parts {
     text { "elm.text";
        desc { "state_begin";
           ...           
        }            
        desc { "state_end";
           ...
        }            
     }    
  }
}
```

If I call `start_my_anim`, it will animate my text, great!

But it will animate with *LINEAR* transition. How can I ask `anim` to use *DECELERATE*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use set_tween_state_anim() instead of set_tween_state() as follows.

```
set_tween_state_anim(PART:"elm.text", "state_begin", 0.0, "state_end", 0.0, DECELERATE, pos);
//There are some transition modes. (e.g. LINEAR, ACCELERATE, DECELERATE, etc.)
```

BTW, the last parameter of anim() is passed as the value parameter of the script function.

```
public my_anim(val, Float:pos) {
    if (val == 9) { // This is the last parameter of anim function.
        set_tween_state(PART:"elm.text", pos, "state_begin", 0.0, "state_end", 0.0);
    }
}
public start_my_anim() {
    anim(1, "my_anim", 9); // The last parameter is passed as the value parameter of the script function.
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I didn't give a chance to `set_tween_state_anim` earlier, as my EDC Editor is not coloring it to green, just like it does for `set_tween_state`.

Comment: By any chance can you share a list of available commands please?

Comment: I checks commands in the following file.
https://git.enlightenment.org/core/efl.git/tree/data/edje/include/edje.inc

But some of commands are not supported by Tizen.

Comment: Can you please look at my other Tizen issue with SVG: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939893/svg-is-not-displayed-after-migrating-from-tizen4-to-tizen5-5-neither-in-emulato Sorry for asking this here, but there is no available forum where I can get in touch. JIRA is not working, facebook is handled by a bot. forum is not sending email